# Circuit to measure current in high voltage, high frequency transformer

Tags: current-measurement, high-voltage, high-frequency

Next it is a simplified circuit diagram for high frequency transformer (50 kHz) which supplies a cathode-ray tube:

[image]

Colored parts are intended to measure load current by ADC of microcontroller; magnitude of load current is around 3mA (maximum).

As electronic hobbyist I am familiar with some blocks, but I am lacking knowledge about diode circuits, so these are my questions:

1. Blue block. C55 stabilize signal and Z5 protect ADC input from over voltage. Right?
2. Red block. R55 and R4 make a voltage divider but, What is the function of diode D4?
3. Green block. I do not really understand at all function of these components. I am familiar with zener diodes used as voltage reference or clamp element but this way of connection is new for me.
4. Yellow block. R1, R2 and R3 form a voltage divider. Right?

Schematics and values were obtained from a very old design. I will simplify circuit merging some components. I have already run some simulations in Proteus changing RL value, and ADC-MCU probe always shows same value (~2.82V).

If anybody has expertise in this type of circuits I will appreciate the help and guidance in this topic, or if there is any suggestion to measure load current it will be welcome. My biggest doubt is how is it possible this circuit works? I had have a hard time looking information on internet and I have found nothing similar to points me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, Petirrojo.  Some of your circuit is perhaps mis-drawn.  Z2 is backwards? The transformer and D1 should return to ground?  

You are correct that the circuit as drawn does not measure the current through RL.  Check the wiring again.

Comment: Hello @user69795. I have carefully studied closely this circuit, each component is as the original design. D1 and C1 clamp voltage for RL. Is Z2 backward? Maybe, design can be wrong. As I have mentioned before, I do not have enough knowledge to judge or correct this circuit.

Comment: That circuit does not measure current from the transformer.

Comment: IMO, this circuit can't be more wrong as it is. C1 and D1 are part of incomplete voltage doubler, The voltage divider has an insane low resistance for kV measurement, there is no reference potential defined, ... so on.

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified too much? - leaving out other circuit parts that would make its function more clear. So far, this may be part of the C.R.T. supply that drives the cathode or grid. Including the actual C.R.T. connections may help us help you.

Comment: Hello MarkoBuršič and @glen_geek. Thanks for your observations. C1 and D1 are half part of one stage voltage doubler, design has three stages of CW voltage multiplier. Mr. Glen, transformer and CW circuit feed the anode of C.R.T, filament (cathode) is supplied by 1.5V@3A DC source and shares same ground with this circuit. If you think I should put more parts an information of the circuit to illustrate clearer the question and make it useful for others, let me know.